# Is there a way to add sound effects when pressing a button in shoes Gui?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, shoes

We are using ubuntu server and we are using the language of Ruby.
Also, we are using shoes for the GUI.

Is there a way to add sound effects when pressing a button or music in general in shoes(GUI).

For the music, I downloaded the gem win32 and I think it works but is there any other gem that works.

Thank you